# Pointwise and uniform boundedness of sequence of functions

Tags: real-analysis

Define the sequence of functions $f_n:(0,1)\to\mathbb{R}$ by:

$$f_n(x):=1/x.$$

I *believe* the sequence of functions $\{f_n\}$ are pointwise bounded but **not** uniformly bounded. Furthermore, for example, take $M(x):=\frac{1}{x-1}$, then $\left|f_n(x)\right|\leq M(x)$ $\forall x$ and for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$. My question is, is this correct? Also, why is the sequence of functions
$f_n(x):=n$ not uniformly bounded or pointwise bounded? I would think I could simply take $M:=n+1$, then obviously $\left|f_n(x)\right|\leq M$ $\forall x$ and for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$. However, this is not the case, and so my question is why? Can neither $M$ or $M(x)$ depend on $n$?

Comment: You are asking multiple questions, its becoming confusing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pointwise bounded means there exists $M$ possibly depending on $x$ such that $f_n(x) \leq M$ for all $n$ and $x$. As you have observes $M(x)=\frac 1 x$ does the job.

Uniformly bounded means the bound $M$ above is not allowed to depend on $x$. Suppose $f_n(x) <M$ for all $x$ and $n$. Take any $x \in (0,\frac 1M)$ to get  a contradiction. Hence, the sequence is not uniformly bounded.

$f_n(x)=n$ is not even pointwise bounded because there is no constant $M$, not depending on $n$ but possibly depending on $x$, such that $f_n(x) <M$ for all $n$ and all $x$. .

Comment: So, what about the boundedness of the sequence of functions defined as $f_n(x):=n$? That is, what is wrong with the following: Let $M:=n+1$. Then $|f_n(x)|\leq M$ hence $\{f_n\}$ is uniformly bounded.

Comment: @D.Math Answer edited.

Comment: So, for pointwise bounded the $M$ can only depend on $x$ and *not* $n$?

Comment: Yes, $M$ cannot depend on $n$.